Why Can't I update my contentful entry with ruby gem
I'm currently trying to update entries in contentful using ruby's gem (contentful-management).
But it doesn't work.
There are no errors and I can't pinpoint the cause.
Below is the code and error.
Help me.
Here is my code.
contentful-management (3.10.0)

class Contentful::UpdateWorkService
  CONTENT_TYPE_ID = 'hoge'
  def initialize(entry_id)
    @entry_id = entry_id
    @client = Contentful::Management::Client.new(ENV['CONTENTFUL_CMA_ACCESS_TOKEN'])
    @environment = @client.environments(ENV['CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID']).find(ENV['CONTENTFUL_ENVIRONMENT'])
  end

  def execute
    published_entry = entry
    published_entry.title = @story.title
    published_entry.description = @story.description
    published_entry.save
    published_entry.publish
  end

  private

  def entry
    @environment.entries.find(@entry_id)
  end
end


This is my logs.
[11] pry(main)> reload! && Contentful::UpdateWorkService.new("MY_ENTRY_ID").execute
Reloading...
=> #<Contentful::Management::Entry: @sys={:space=>#<Contentful::Management::Link: @sys={:type=>"Link", :linkType=>"Space", :id=>"MY_SPAFE_ID"}>, :id=>"MY_ENTRY_ID", :type=>"Entry", :createdAt=>Wed, 03 Apr 2024 05:45:38 +0000, :updatedAt=>Wed, 03 Apr 2024 05:52:10 +0000, :environment=>#<Contentful::Management::Link: @sys={:id=>"master", :type=>"Link", :linkType=>"Environment"}>, :publishedVersion=>3, :publishedAt=>Wed, 03 Apr 2024 05:52:10 +0000, :firstPublishedAt=>"2024-04-03T05:45:47.016Z", :createdBy=>#<Contentful::Management::Link: @sys={:type=>"Link", :linkType=>"User", :id=>"MY_USER_ID"}>, :updatedBy=>#<Contentful::Management::Link: @sys={:type=>"Link", :linkType=>"User", :id=>"MY_USER_ID"}>, :publishedCounter=>2, :version=>4, :publishedBy=>#<Contentful::Management::Link: @sys={:type=>"Link", :linkType=>"User", :id=>"MY_USER_ID"}>, :automationTags=>[], :contentType=>#<Contentful::Management::Link: @sys={:type=>"Link", :linkType=>"ContentType", :id=>"works_v2"}>, :urn=>"crn:contentful:::content:spaces/MY_SPAFE_ID/environments/master/entries/MY_ENTRY_ID", :locale=>"en-US"} @_metadata={:tags=>[]}>


What exactly doesn't work? Please edit your question and add specific observations and what you would expect to happen.

Based on what you have provided there is no way you do not receive any errors. For one @story is not defined so at a minimum this would be a NoMethodError
